# Pascal. Проблема с сортировкой

Tags: сортировка, pascal

Есть подключеный модуль в котором есть процедура для сортировки массива (числа вводим в StringGrid (10 чисел). Но при выполнении программы, сортировки нет. Числа выводятся в обычном порядке.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids, MySort;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  a : array [0..9] of integer;
  sum, k : integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var j : integer;
begin
  for j:=0 to 9 do
    a[j]:=StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[j,0]);
  Srt(a);
  for j:=0 to 9 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(a[j]));
    //StringGrid1.Cells[j,0]:=IntToStr(a[j+1]);
end;

end.
```

Модуль

```
unit MySort;

interface
procedure Srt(arr : array of integer);

implementation

procedure Srt;
var i,j, buf : integer;
  begin
    for i:=1 to 9 do
      for j:=i+1 to 10 do
        if arr[i]>arr[j] then
        begin
          buf:=arr[i];
          arr[i]:=arr[j];
          arr[j]:=buf;
        end;

  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Массив передается по значению - то есть в функцию попадает его копия. Заведите ссылочный тип.

```
unit MySort;

interface

type
  TIntArray: array of integer;

procedure Srt(arr: TIntArray);

implementation

procedure Srt;
var 
  i,j, buf: integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 9 do
    for j:=i+1 to 10 do
      if arr[i]>arr[j] then
      begin
        buf:=arr[i];
        arr[i]:=arr[j];
        arr[j]:=buf;
      end;
end;

end.

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: integer;
  a: TIntArray;
begin
  SetLength(a, 10);
  for j:=0 to 9 do
    a[j]:=StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[j,0]);
  Srt(a);
  for j:=0 to 9 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(a[j]));
    //StringGrid1.Cells[j,0]:=IntToStr(a[j+1]);
end;
```

Comment: А можно уточнить. Куда это писать?